# Multiple CASE in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, case

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC_VuReg]   
     @PACKAGEDESCR VARCHAR(50),
     @VOUCHERFROMDT VARCHAR(20),
     @VOUCHERTODT VARCHAR(20),
     @STATUS VARCHAR(10),
     @RefNo VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @sQRY = 'SELECT * FROM VuReg WHERE PACKAGEDESCR = ''' + @PACKAGEDESCR  +
                 ''' AND VOUCHERDT BETWEEN ''' + @VOUCHERFROMDT + ''' AND ''' +  @VOUCHERTODT + 
                 ''' AND SUBACTIVITY = CASE WHEN LEN(''' + @RefNo + ''') > 0 THEN ''' + @RefNo + ''' ELSE SUBACTIVITY END AND WDNO = CASE WHEN ''' + @STATUS  + ''' =''NULL'' THEN IS NULL WHEN '''+ @STATUS   + ''' =  ''NOT NULL'' THEN  IS NOT NULL WHEN '''+ @STATUS   + ''' =  '''' THEN  WDNO END '

   --print @sqry
   EXEC sp_executesql @sqry
END
```

In the above procedure, everything has worked perfectly before adding the parameter `@Status`.

If `@status` is `NULL`, then the condition will be

```
SELECT * FROM VuReg WHERE WDNO IS NULL
```

If `@status` is `NOT NULL`, then the condition will be

```
SELECT * FROM VuReg WHERE WDNO IS NOT NULL
```

And if `@status` is `''`, then the condition will be

```
SELECT * FROM VuReg WHERE WDNO = WDNO
```

{expect all the record}

Comment: Your code is almost impossible to detangle.  You are using `sp_executesql`.  You should start by writing the code to make use of parameters, instead of stuffing the values into strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without dynamic sql.

```
create procedure dbo.proc_VuReg
    @packagedescr varchar(50)
  , @voucherfromdt varchar(20)
  , @vouchertodt varchar(20)
  , @status varchar(10)
  , @RefNo varchar(10)
as
begin;
set nocount on;

select  * 
from VuReg 
where packagedescr = @packagedescr  
  and voucherdt between @voucherfromdt and @vouchertodt 
  and (subactivity = @RefNo or @RefNo is null)
  and ( 
       (@status = 'null' and wdno is null)
    or (@status = 'not null' and wdno is not null)
    or @status = ''
    )
option(recompile) /* generates a new execution plan for each execution to help accommodate the conditional logic in the where clause */
end;
```

If you still want to go dynamic, do it correctly. Start with these:

- [An Updated "Kitchen Sink" Example - Aaron Bertand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/)
- [Parameter Sniffing, Embedding, and the RECOMPILE Options - Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options)
- [Dynamic Search Conditions - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)
- [Catch-all queries - Gail Shaw](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)